# Dockerized Solr not updating configsets

Tags: docker, solr

I have a Dockerized Solr and I have to update a configset. The file I modified is under this path: `solrhome/server/solr/configsets/myconfig/conf` and is called `DIH_ContentIndex.xml`. After that, I deleted my Docker images and containers with these commands:

```
docker container stop <solr_container_id>
docker container rm <solr_container_id>
docker image rm <solr_img_id>
docker volume rm <solr_volume>
```

I rebuilt everything but Solr is not taking changes, as I can see when i go in the `Files` section. So, I decided to add a configset, that we will call `newconfig` with my changes at the same level of the other one. Redid everything and restarted. But nothing. So, I decided to enter the container with `docker exec -it --user root <solr_container_id> /bin/bash` and decided to change the files manually (just to test). Stopped, restarted the container but still nothing. After deleting again everything about Docker, I can still see my changes from inside the container. At this point, I think either I'm not deleting everything or I'm not placing my new config in the right directory. What else do I need to do for a clean build?

Here is the fragment of `docker-compose` I'm trying to launch, just in case this is the fault.

```
solr:
    container_name: "MySolr"
    build: ./solr
    restart: always
    hostname: solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    networks:
     - my-network
    volumes:
     - vol_solr:/opt/solr
    depends_on:
     - configdb
     - zookeeper
    environment:
        ZK_HOST: zookeeper:2181
```

Of course, everything else is running fine so there is no error witht he dependencies.

It is not a problem of browser cache. I already tried cleaning the cache and using a different browser.

Some updates: it actually copies my config inside the fresh-built image.. But still, can't select it from the Frontend. Clearly, I'm placing my config files in the wrong path.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By default (when starting in cloud mode, which it seems you are since you depend on zookeeper)  the configuration lives inside zookeeper; files on disk is generally not consulted. https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/config-sets.html#configsets-in-solrcloud-clusters - Use the Configsets API or `zkCli` and `upconfig` to upload new configuration.

Comment: i see. i was thinking about that.. i have zookeeper locally, but i will definitely check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! All I had to do was:

- enter the Solr container, with this command:

  `docker exec -it --user root <solr_container_id> /bin/bash`

  **entering as root to be able to install** `nano`
- copy my pre-existing config somewhere (in the same path of bin for convenience) and modify the file DIH_ContentIndex.xml

  `apt update`
  `apt install nano`
  `nano DIH_ContentIndex.xml`
- Go to `solr/bin` pload to ZK, using this command:

  `solr zk upconfig -n config_name -d /path/to/config_folder`